# Equal Equilateralizer Point in a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, triangles, polyhedra

A triangle has the [congruent isoscelizers point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_isoscelizers_point) and [equal parallelians point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_parallelians_point).

I'm pretty sure that any tetrahedron has many cutting planes that will cut an equilateral triangle.  Is that much true -- that any three leg [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) has equilateral triangle cutting planes?

If so, is there a point of concurrence for 4 of these cutting planes?

If so, is there a point where 4 congruent equilateral triangles get cut?

If not that, is there a point where 4 congruent triangles gets cut?

Comment: If a solid angle admits an equilateral cutting plane then there is such a plane through every point within this solid angle, and if every solid angle admits such a plane then every point in the interior of a tetrahedron belongs  to four such planes.

Comment: Alternative generalizations ... Let a "trisohedralizer" of tetrahedron $OABC$ w.r.t. $O$ be a plane that meets edges $OA$, $OB$, $OC$ in $A^\prime$, $B^\prime$, $C^\prime$ such that tet $OA^\prime B^\prime C^\prime$ is "trisohedral": the three faces meeting at $O$ have equal area; we'll call the fourth face of that tetrahedron the *base* of the trisohedralizer. Then (barring degeneracies) there exists a unique "equal-area trisohedralizers point", where four trisohedralizers (one for each vertex) with a common base area concur. Likewise, there's a unique "equal-area parallelians point".