# Tetrahedron Centers

Tags: geometry, triangles, polyhedra, solid-geometry

For [Triangle Centers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCenter.html), as seen at the [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html), the various centers each have a [triangle center function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCenterFunction.html) $f(a,b,c)$ that is homogeneous, bisymmetric, and cyclic within [barycentric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) or [trilinear](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrilinearCoordinates.html) coordinates.  Here are functions for [centers known to Euclid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TriangleCalculator/).

```
      name               trilinear  barycentric
X_1   incenter       I   1          a                 angle bisectors  
X_2   centroid       G   1/a        1                 medians
X_3   circumcenter   O   cos(A)     a^2(b^2+c^2-a)    perpendicular bisectors  
X_4   orthocenter    H   sec(A)     tan(A)            altitudes
```

> Are there tetrahedron center functions similar to the triangle center functions in barycentric or trilinear coordinates? The barycentric centroid and  trilinear incenter are known.

[image]

I've made an elaborate [Tetrahedron Centers](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TetrahedronCenters/) demonstration, and posted code showing  [$4 \pi =2 \sum dihedral - \sum solid $](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolidAndDihedralAnglesOfATetrahedron/) . At [fermat point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842409/fermat-point-of-a-tetrahedron) I give exact coordinates of centers for a specific tetrahedron. At [Dihedral Constant Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850117/the-dihedral-constant-center-of-a-tetrahedron) some exact coordinates are calculated for a new tetrahedron center.

Some available items for tetrahedron $ABCD$ are :
volume, total surface area, total perimeter, dihedral constant.
solid angle $A$, face area $A$ ($\triangle BCD$), perimeter $A$ ... $B$ ... $C$ ... $D$
edge length $ab$, dihedral angle $ab$ ... $ac$ ... $ad$ ... $bc$ ... $bd$ ... $cd$

I'd like to get a list of tetrahedron center functions started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the comparatively-easy ones ...

As in [my other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863851/409), given tetrahedron $PABC$, I use barycentric coordinates $\rho$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ to parameterize the point of interest as
$$\frac{\rho\,P + \alpha\,A + \beta\, B + \gamma\,C}{\rho + \alpha + \beta + \gamma}$$

We'll take $V$ to be the volume of the tetrahedron. Other elements (side-lengths, face-areas, dihedral angles) are as labeled in the figure:

[image]

Of note:

- Opposite edge-pairs are $(a,d)$, $(b,e)$, $(c,f)$.
- Edges surrounding vertices $P$, $A$, $B$, $C$ are $(a,b,c)$, $(a,e,f)$, $(d,b,f)$, $(d,e,c)$.
- Edges surrounding faces $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are $(d,e,f)$, $(d,b,c)$, $(a,e,c)$, $(a,b,f)$.

See the [addendum to this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2861985/409) about how to convert edge-length expressions into *hedronometric* (face-area-based) forms, which *may* be more appropriate in this context. (Finding the "best" hedronometric form is something of a challenge.)

---

**Centroid ($G$)**

$$\rho : \alpha : \beta : \gamma  \;=\;  1 : 1 : 1 : 1$$

---

**Incenter ($I$)**

$$\rho : \alpha : \beta : \gamma  \;=\;  W : X : Y : Z$$

---

**Circumcenter ($O$)**

$$\begin{align}\rho &=\phantom{+} a^2 d^2 \left(-d^2 + e^2 + f^2 \right) \\
&\phantom{=}+ b^2 e^2 \left(\phantom{-}d^2 - e^2 + f^2 \right) \\[4pt]
&\phantom{=}+ c^2 f^2 \left(\phantom{-}d^2 + e^2 - f^2 \right) \\[4pt]
&\phantom{=}- 2 d^2 e^2 f^2 \\[8pt]
&= 18 V^2 - a^2\,W X \cos D - b^2\,W Y \cos E - c^2\,W Z \cos F
\end{align}$$

---

**Nine/Twelve-Point Center ($T$)**

(I'm taking this to mean the center of sphere through the centroids of the faces, which also contains other points of interest, as described in the [Wikipedia "Tetrahedron" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Properties_analogous_to_those_of_a_triangle).)

$$\begin{align}\rho \;=\; &\phantom{-\;} 2 a^2 d^2 \left(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \right) +   a^2 d^2 \left(-d^2 + e^2 + f^2 \right) \\[4pt]
&+ 2 b^2 e^2 \left(\phantom{-}a^2 - b^2 + c^2 \right) +   b^2 e^2 \left(\phantom{-}d^2 - e^2 + f^2 \right) \\[4pt]
&+ 2 c^2 f^2 \left(\phantom{-}a^2 + b^2 - c^2 \right) +   c^2 f^2 \left(\phantom{-}d^2 + e^2 - f^2 \right) \\[4pt]
&- 2 b^2 c^2 d^2 - 2 a^2 c^2 e^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 f^2
\end{align}$$

---

**Isogonal Conjugates, and the Symmedian Point ($K$)**

According to the *Forum Geometricorum* article ["Isogonal Conjugates in a Tetrahedron" (PDF)](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2016volume16/FG201606.pdf) by Sadek, et al., if isogonal conjugates have barycentric coordinates $(\rho,\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and $(\rho^\prime, \alpha^\prime, \beta^\prime, \gamma^\prime)$, then

$$\frac{\rho\rho^\prime}{W^2} = \frac{\alpha\alpha^\prime}{X^2} = \frac{\beta\beta^\prime}{Y^2} = \frac{\gamma\gamma^\prime}{Z^2}$$

(This result reconfirms that the Incenter ($I$) is its own isogonal conjugate. But I digress ...) Thus,
$$\rho^\prime : \alpha^\prime : \beta^\prime : \gamma^\prime \;=\; \frac{W^2}{\rho} : \frac{X^2}{\alpha} = \frac{Y^2}{\beta} = \frac{Z^2}{\gamma}$$

Since the Symmedian Point ($K$) is the isogonal conjugate of the centroid ($G$), its barycentric coordinates satisfy

$$\rho : \alpha : \beta : \gamma \;=\; W^2 : X^2 : Y^2 : Z^2$$

---

**Monge Point ($M$)**

$$\begin{align}
\rho &=\phantom{+}a^2d^2 \left(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2\right) \\[4pt]
&\phantom{=\,}+ b^2 e^2 \left(\phantom{-}a^2 - b^2 + c^2\right) \\[4pt]
&\phantom{=\,}+ c^2 f^2 \left(\phantom{-}a^2 + b^2 - c^2\right) \\[4pt]
&\phantom{=\,}+ d^2 e^2 f^2 - b^2 c^2 d^2 - a^2 c^2 e^2 - a^2 b^2 f^2
\end{align}$$

---

**Spieker Point ($S$)**

The Spieker Point is the incenter of the *medial tetrahedron* (ie, the tetrahedron whose vertices are the centroids of the faces) of $PABC$.

By the Incenter formula above, $S$ is given by

$$\frac{W^\prime\,P^\prime + X^\prime\,A^\prime + Y^\prime\,B^\prime + Z^\prime\,C^\prime}{W^\prime + X^\prime + Y^\prime + Z^\prime}$$

for the medial tetrahedron with vertices $P^\prime = \frac13(A+B+C)$, etc, and face-areas $W^\prime = \frac19 W$, etc. This can be re-written as

$$\frac{\frac13(X+Y+Z)\,P + \frac13(W+Y+Z)\,A + \frac13(W+X+Z)\,B + \frac13(W+X+Y)\,C}{W + X + Y + Z}$$
from which we observe
$$\rho : \alpha : \beta : \gamma \;=\; X + Y + Z : W + Y + Z : W + X + Z : W + Z + Y $$

---

**Orthocenter ($H$)**

In general, a tetrahedron does not have an orthocenter. Equivalent conditions that force a tetrahedron to be orthocentric are
$$a^2 + d^2 = b^2 + e^2 = c^2 + f^2 $$
$$\cos A \cos D = \cos B \cos E = \cos C \cos F$$
$$\overrightarrow{PA}\perp\overrightarrow{BC} \qquad \overrightarrow{PB}\perp\overrightarrow{CA} \qquad \overrightarrow{PC}\perp\overrightarrow{AB}$$

Note: If any two orthogonality conditions hold, then the third one rides for free.

Symmetric-looking barycentric coordinates for the orthocenter of such a tetrahedron are a bit elusive. I'll have to come back to this.

---

---

**Edit. (17 October, 2023. Five years later!)** I'm expanding this compilation with a couple of items from OP's recent questions.

---

**Tangential Tetrahedron** ([question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4786342/409))

Let $P'A'B'C'$ be a tetrahedron tangent to the circumsphere of $PABC$ at its vertices, with $P'$ opposite the face tangent to $P$, etc. Barycentric coordinates of $P'$ are ...

$$\begin{align}
-2d^2e^2f^2
&:\,d^2(-a^2d^2+b^2e^2+c^2f^2) \\
&:\,e^2(\phantom{-}a^2d^2-b^2e^2+c^2f^2) \\
&:f^2(\phantom{-}a^2d^2+b^2e^2-c^2f^2)
\end{align}$$

---

**Extangents Tetrahedron** (mentioned in comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4786342/409))

Let $P'A'B'C'$ be the "outer" tetrahedron such that plane $A'B'C'$ is tangent to the exspheres of $PABC$ opposite vertices $A$, $B$, $C$; etc. Barycentric coordinates of $P'$ are ...

$$\begin{align}
 - W(3 + \cos A + \cos B + \cos C ) 
&: X(1 + \cos D + \cos B + \cos C ) \\
&: Y(1 + \cos A + \cos E + \cos C ) \\
&: Z(1 + \cos A + \cos B + \cos F )
\end{align}$$

The shaded tetrahedron is the extangents tetrahedron:

[image]

Comment: These are brilliant.  I usually substitute Monge for the Orthocenter.  I believe when H=M when H exists.  The Fermat point is on my want list.  Interesting that K is the 2nd power point.  
We can calculate the Euler line.   In a triangle, the incenter can be added and the Euler line and 3 induced Euler lines concur.  Are there points like that in a Tetrahedron?

Comment: Also need to look at anticomplementary, contact, excentral, extangents, extouch, incentral, medial, orthic, and tangential tetrahedra.

Comment: So there exists a tetrahedral analogue to the “isogonal conjugate”, but what about the “isotomic conjugate” (as well as the “[cyclocevian conjugate](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/glossary.html#:~:text=Cyclocevian%20Conjugate)”)?

Comment: @user688486: The Wolfram Function Repo defines [IsotomicConjugate](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IsotomicConjugate/). In bary-coords, the conj of $U=(r:s:t:u)$ is $U'=(1/r:1/s:1/t:1/u)$. Geometrically, cevians through $U$ and $U'$ from a tet vertex meet the opposite face in pts that are in turn isotomic conjugates with respect to that face. (This is analogous to the triangle case, where the cevians from a vertex meet the opposite edge in "isotomic conjugates" (having reciprocal bary-coords) with respect to that edge.) ... I haven't checked about cyclocevians.

Comment: @Blue Thanks! Strangely, whereas the trilinear coordinate system is [much more popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_triangle_geometry#Definition_of_triangle_center) than the barycentric coordinate system in Euclidean triangle geometry,  the homologous tetraplanar coordinate system has almost never (Why?) been as popular as the corresponding barycentric coordinate system in ℝ³. Can [those formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates#Formulas) be generalized to tetraplanar coordinates as well?

Comment: @user688486: My system of choice is barycentric (for both triangles and tetrahedra); treating a point as a weighted average of vertices is simple and intuitive. (That the [ETC](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) tends to favor trilinears makes consulting, say, the [glossary](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/glossary.html) more work for me. This may someday drive me to switch allegiances.) Tetraplanars may be less common for whatever-reason, but they *work*. So, one can indeed use them to capture notions of parallelism, concurrency, etc.

Comment: In addition, although Kimberling's points (centers and bicentric pairs) are the centre of attention for most people at present, algebraic curves (central lines, inconics, circumconics, triangle cubics, etc.) are getting more and more regard in planar triangle geometry. In accordance with the Wikipedia article, both the Euler line and the nine-point circle can be generalized. In view of these, can something like the Feuerbach hyperbola, the Neuberg cubic, and the Steiner deltoid be generalized likewise?

Comment: @Blue Many thanks. I notice that MathWorld also refers to the [tripolar coordinate system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/mathworld/Tripolar_Coordinates/); can the cited "Euler 1786" equation be extended to quadripolar coordinates on tetrahedra? Moreover, as the Desargues's theorem (as well as the Menelaus's theorem and the Ceva's theorem) can be extended into 3D, can [the trilinear pole and the trilinear polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_polarity#:~:text=Desargues%27%20theorem) also be extended to points and planes associated with tetrahedra?

Comment: @user688486: Some things get just a little bit trickier with tetrahedra. Concurrencies are harder to guarantee (eg, no orthocenter). Circumquadrics require *five* non-vertex pts compared to triangle circumconics needing only *two*, and higher-degree surfaces require even more. So, how (and *whether*) things generalize seems to require consideration on a case-by-case basis. ... But at least trilinear poles and polars generalize directly, with comparable formulas. ... (Extended discussion warning. This may be my last reply.)

Comment: Thanks very much! Given that the orthocentre (point of concurrence of three lines) has to be generalised to the Monge point (intersection of six or four planes), I reckon that the concept of planes effectively makes more sense than that of lines in modern tetrahedron geometry.

Comment: [It is said that](http://doi.org/10.1007/s10957-014-0684-6) in a tetrahedron, there actually exists the **second** symmedian point (although the authors use the term “Lemoine point”). Reasons: Note that in a triangle, the centroid minimizes the sum of squared (Euclidean) distances between itself and each _vertex_, and the symmedian point minimizes that between itself and each _side_; in a tetrahedron, the centroid is still the point with a minimal sum of squared distances from the (four) *vertices*, yet now there are two  objects, i.e., *faces* and *edges* …. How about the other Lemoine point?

Comment: @user688486: *"How about the other Lemoine point?"* I don't have a ready answer for that, and finding one seems a bit computationally difficult. I'll have to give it some thought. ... I'll double-up on this comment to note that our previous exchange inspired me to do a separate investigation of the Monge pt: I've determined that any circumhyperboloid whose intersections with the faces are rectangular hyperbolas has its center at the Monge pt. This is comparable —though not directly analogous— to the fact that a circumhyperbola of a triangle is rectangular iff it contains the orthocenter.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [this previous question by OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104646/equal-equilateralizer-point-in-a-tetrahedron), I investigated "hedronometric" (face-area-based) counterparts of a triangle's Congruent Isoscelizers Point and Congruent Parallelians Point. [I wrote a note about them.](http://dlnds.com/mathdocs/Hedronometric-Parallelians-and-Trisohedralizers.pdf)

In the following, barycentric coordinates $\rho$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ describe the point
$$\frac{\rho\,P + \alpha\,A + \beta\,B + \gamma\,C}{\rho + \alpha + \beta + \gamma} \tag{$\star$}$$
The corresponding trilinear (er, um, *tetraplanar*) coordinates of the point derive by dividing each barycentric by the area of the appropriate opposite face (here, $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$):

$$\frac{\rho}{W} : \frac{\alpha}{X} : \frac{\beta}{Y} : \frac{\gamma}{Z} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

**Equal-Area Parallelians Point**

> **Definition and Theorem.** A *parallelian* of tetrahedron $PABC$ with respect to vertex $P$ is a triangle, with vertices on the edge-lines through $P$, in a plane parallel to that of $\triangle ABC$. Any non-degenerate tetrahedron admits a unique point common to the planes of four equal-area parallelians (one for each vertex); this is the *Equal-Area Parallelians Point* (EAPP).

The barycentric coordinates of the EAPP are
$$\rho =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{W}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{Y}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\qquad 
\alpha =\phantom{-}\frac{1}{\sqrt{W}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{X}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{Y}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\qquad\text{etc} \tag{1}$$

---

**Equal-Area Trisohedralizers Point**

> **Definition and Theorem.** A *trisohedralizer* of a tetrahedron $PABC$ with respect to vertex $P$ is a triangle $\triangle A^\prime B^\prime C^\prime$, with vertices on the edge-lines through $P$, that serves as a base for a "trisohedral" tetrahedron. (That is, $|\triangle PB^\prime C^\prime| = |\triangle P C^\prime A^\prime| = |\triangle P A^\prime B^\prime |$.) Any non-degenerate triangle admits a unique point common to the planes of four equal-area trisohedralizers (one for each vertex); this is the *Equal-Area Trisohedralizers Point* (EATP).

The barycentric coordinates of the EATP are
$$\rho = W \left(\;2\sqrt{W/\lambda_P} - \sqrt{X/\lambda_A} - \sqrt{Y/\lambda_B} - \sqrt{Z/\lambda_C}\;\right) \qquad \text{etc} \tag{2}$$
where
$$\lambda_V^2 \;=\; 3 - 2\;\sum_{\theta} \cos\theta \tag{3}$$
with the sum taken over the three dihedral angles along edges emanating from vertex $V$.

Comment: Neat!  How about I O H T K S X M?